# Wcf Service method Design

Tags: wcf, wcf-ria-services

I have a Wcf service that serves up a collection of products List to two Different ViewModels.

- ViewModel 1 calls WCF Service to Get a collection of Products
- ViewModel 2 calls WCF Service to Get a collection of Products

Is it bad practice to lable my WCF service methods like this

1. List MyWCFSerive.GetProductsForViewModel1()
2. List MyWCFSerive.GetProductsForViewModel2()

Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that would be bad practice, you'd be coupling your service to a particular presentation implementation and technology.

What happens when you want a list of products on an MVC site via the same service?

If both view models retrieve the same collection of products, then they should invoke the same service method. If each view displays a different collection of products, then the methods should be named based on how the collections differ, for example if different filtering is applied then this should be implied by the method names.

Comment: Do you have any other better alternative?  I could eventually need to extend this to 3 or 4 different UI interfaces

Comment: How does each view of the data differ?

Comment: Well I have a PriceQuoteViewModel that can only show live price quotes for very few Products (basically because the functionality has not been extended to many products yet). I also have a second ViewModel called WizardPricerViewModel that will let you request prices from a dealer but they dont show live price quotes.

Comment: Maybe my WCF methods could be GetLiveQuoteProducts and GetRequestQuoteProducts?

Comment: Yes, they sound more appropriate

Comment: Thanks - Could I also go off the subject slightly and ask if Datacontracts that are sent back from my WCF service can be used as Models in my MVVM or should i convert them to CLient Side Models?

Comment: I see you've asked this as another question, so I have answered it there.